# I can't make the body background appear in the middle with no-repeat

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background for my page, and I want it to appear in middle. But for some reason it shows on the left, no matter what I do.

```
body
{ 
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size:12px;  
    color:#696969; 
    text-align:center; 
    min-width:320px; 
    background:url(../images/background.jpg) center no-repeat; 
    position:relative; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; 
}
```

I have created a separate file and it showed in middle with the following code:

```
<style>
    body{
        background:url('background.jpg') center no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

why doesn't it work on my original page? Any suggestion?

Comment: get rid of the position:relative; (and probably min-width)

Answer (score 0):

After testing both of your methods, I got it working with this:

```
// style.css
body
{ 
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; 
    font-size:12px;  
    color:#696969; 
    text-align:center; 
    min-width:320px; 
    background:url(bg.jpg) center top no-repeat; 
    position:relative; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none; 
}

// index.html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my output:

[image]

(the image was randomly chosen from a google search)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
background:url(image1.jpg) center top no-repeat;
```